# cant move the text near each other

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

Hello i having some problem design the app I working on
I'm trying to make the TextEdit and The TextView be near each other but they still at the same place
i'm using a grid layout because I want the app be available for all sizes of all the devices
i'm kind of a beginner so I don't understand so much on developing android apps

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="7">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/WelcomeText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="Welcome To My App"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="Please fill the information"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:text="Name:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:a
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/nameTxt"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:ems="14"
        android:capitalize="sentences"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phoneTxt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:text="Phone:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Phone"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:ems="14"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emailTxt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:text="Email:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Email"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:ems="14"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ageTxt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:text="Age:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Age"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:ems="14"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="Age:"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        />
</GridLayout>
```

[how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w1eV.png)

the red arrows represent where I want the EditText to be (at the end of each Text View)

Comment: try to give weights to the corresponding elements of same row.

Comment: Personally I think `RelativeLayout` is better suited for what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bring "info" and "WelcomeText" and "nextBtn" out of "GridLayout", then add LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="576dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/WelcomeText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="Welcome To My App"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="Please fill the information"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="7">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:text="Name:"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Name"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/nameTxt"
            android:a
            android:capitalize="sentences"
            android:ems="14"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phoneTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:text="Phone:"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Phone"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:ems="14"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:text="Email:"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Email"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:ems="14"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ageTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:text="Age:"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Age"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="5"
            android:ems="14"
            android:hint="Age:"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:visibility="visible" />


    </GridLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:text="Next" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: another question how I can make the button to be in same line(vertical) with the edit text?

Comment: change the "android:layout_gravity="left" in nextBtn

Comment: I tried it for some reason it doesn't work
(I want that the button end where the edit texts ends how I can do that?)

Comment: you can use margin to move "nextBtn" .   android:layout_marginLeft="50px"